# Python: How to modify data with null in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have  a set of data where some sets of data contains a row `'null'` which need to corrected.

There is the rule to correct the data in `pandas` dataframe.

1. When Volume is `null`, change to `0`.
2. `Open`, `High`, `Low`, `Close` follow the Close of previous day. Mean `2016-6-29` which has `null` will follow Close of `2016-6-28` which is `0.6`
3. If the first row is null, it will `volume = 0` and `Open`, `high`,`Low` `Close`, follow the next day Open value.

   ```
   >>df_a   
   Date,Stock,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume
   2016-06-22,AWG,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0
   2016-06-23,AWG,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0
   2016-06-24,AWG,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0
   2016-06-27,AWG,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,800
   2016-06-28,AWG,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0
   2016-06-29,AWG,null,null,null,null,null,null
   2016-06-30,AWG,null,null,null,null,null,null
   2016-07-01,AWG,0.620000,0.650000,0.620000,0.650000,0.650000,40000
   2016-07-04,AWG,null,null,null,null,null,null
   2016-07-05,AWG,null,null,null,null,null,null
   2016-07-07,AWG,0.625000,0.650000,0.565000,0.650000,0.650000,3000
   2016-07-08,AWG,0.650000,0.650000,0.650000,0.650000,0.650000,0
   2016-07-11,AWG,0.650000,0.650000,0.605000,0.605000,0.605000,6000
   2016-07-12,AWG,0.640000,0.640000,0.640000,0.640000,0.640000,3300

   >>df_b
   Date,Stock,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume
   2016-06-10,WG,null,null,null,null,null,null
   2016-06-13,WG,null,null,null,null,null,null
   2016-06-14,WG,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,1000
   2016-06-15,WG,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,2000
   2016-06-16,WG,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0
   2016-06-17,WG,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0
   2016-06-20,WG,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0
   2016-06-21,WG,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0
   2016-06-22,WG,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0
   2016-06-23,WG,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0
   2016-06-24,WG,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0
   2016-06-27,WG,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,800
   2016-06-28,WG,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0.600000,0
   2016-06-29,WG,null,null,null,null,null,null
   2016-06-30,WG,null,null,null,null,null,null
   2016-07-01,WG,0.620000,0.650000,0.620000,0.650000,0.650000,40000
   2016-07-04,WG,null,null,null,null,null,null
   2016-07-05,WG,null,null,null,null,null,null
   ```

Part of my code:

```
volume = df_a['Volume'] == 'null'
df_a.loc[volume,'Volume'] = 0
```

However, I unable to continue for `Open`,`High`, `Low` and `Close`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part 1 (Already answered by you)

For a vectorised implementation  its better to convert null to first nan (may be better solution exist )

PART 3 (replace first row )

```
  df.replace('null',np.NaN,inplace=True)
  df.iloc[0].fillna(df.iloc[1].Open,inplace=True)
```

Part 2 (Replace all null values with previous close values ):

```
df['Close'].bfill(inplace=True)
df['Low'].fillna(df['Close'].shift(1),inplace=True)
df['Open'].fillna(df['Close'].shift(1),inplace=True)
df['High'].fillna(df['Close'].shift(1),inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Comment: `df.loc[0] ` return `TypeError: cannot do index indexing on <class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'> with these indexers [0] of <type 'int'>`

Comment: `df.iloc[0].fillna(df.iloc[1].Open,inplace=True)` must also work

Comment: it works now. Can you give details explanation how it works? Thanks

Comment: Just a heads up, `.ix` was deprecated in pandas 0.20, released in May. May want to update based on `.loc` / `.iloc`.

Comment: @behappy Pls mark it as accepted if you find it useful :) . `bfill` is used to fill current row based on previous row .`fillna` used to replace nan values by specified one . `shift` to get value from row shifted by pos (here 1 ) . `inplace` to update the dataframe . Please refer to pandas documentation for more details